# Getting different results from 2-way ANOVA in Matlab vs Python

Tags: anova, python, matlab, statsmodels

I'd like some advice on a two-way ANOVA that I am trying to do. It is an unbalanced design. Here is the full dataset:

| Var1 | Var2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 5.166096057 |
| 3 | 2 | 1.873452551 |
| 3 | 4 | 2.435296493 |
| 3 | 5 | 4.920406303 |
| 3 | 6 | 6.431087505 |
| 2 | 1 | 6.913241927 |
| 2 | 2 | 6.151673113 |
| 2 | 3 | 7.438972122 |
| 1 | 1 | 6.440015518 |
| 1 | 2 | 8.215052128 |
| 3 | 1 | 8.613242957 |
| 3 | 3 | 5.602265279 |
| 3 | 6 | 7.499069032 |
| 2 | 1 | 4.698134824 |
| 2 | 2 | 3.999659812 |
| 2 | 4 | 7.088559399 |
| 2 | 5 | 5.674090984 |
| 2 | 6 | 7.041602744 |
| 1 | 1 | 8.1478138 |
| 1 | 4 | 12.76875557 |
| 1 | 5 | 11.48126021 |
| 1 | 6 | 12.28399779 |
| 3 | 1 | 3.267760697 |
| 3 | 2 | 4.658878193 |
| 3 | 3 | 6.31389484 |
| 3 | 4 | 7.142347999 |
| 3 | 5 | 8.373378188 |
| 3 | 6 | 12.06812441 |
| 2 | 1 | 8.442215852 |
| 2 | 2 | 3.178236868 |
| 2 | 4 | 7.057385213 |
| 2 | 5 | 8.621323999 |
| 2 | 6 | 10.23528979 |

Now, I normally use Matlab for my stats, so I use the `anovan` function which can handle unbalanced designs (https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/anovan.html). I ran my code like so:

```
t = readtable('data_file.xlsx');
data = table2struct(t);
dependent_variable = [data.Result];
independent_variables = {[data.Var1] [data.Var2]};
[p, anova_tbl, stats] = anovan(dependent_variable, independent_variables, 'display', 'off', 'model', 'full', 'varnames', {'Var1', 'Var2'});
```

This code gave me the following result:

```
    {'Source'   }    {'Sum Sq.' }    {'d.f.'}    {'Singular?'}    {'Mean Sq.'}    {'F'       }    {'Prob>F'  }
    {'Var1'     }    {[  7.0599]}    {[   1]}    {[        1]}    {[  7.0599]}    {[  1.4767]}    {[  0.2419]}
    {'Var2'     }    {[ 63.9936]}    {[   4]}    {[        1]}    {[ 15.9984]}    {[  3.3463]}    {[  0.0359]}
    {'Var1*Var2'}    {[ 22.2706]}    {[   9]}    {[        1]}    {[  2.4745]}    {[  0.5176]}    {[  0.8411]}
    {'Error'    }    {[ 76.4950]}    {[  16]}    {[        0]}    {[  4.7809]}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
    {'Total'    }    {[238.5523]}    {[  32]}    {[        0]}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}    {0×0 double}
```

Next, I decided to basically do the same thing, but using the `fitlm` function in Matlab:

```
lm = fitlm(t, 'Result ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var1:Var2');
anova(lm);
```

This gave me the following results:

```
                 SumSq     DF    MeanSq       F         pValue  
                 ______    __    ______    _______    __________

    Var1         60.399     1    60.399     13.521    0.00095409
    Var2         55.076     1    55.076     12.329     0.0014798
    Var1:Var2    1.4436     1    1.4436    0.32317       0.57409
    Error        129.55    29    4.4672
```

As you can see, there are differences in the results. Now, `Var1` and `Var2` are technically categorical/ordinal variables, so I changed the above code to specify that:

```
t2 = t;
t2.Var1 = categorical(t2.Var1);
t2.Var2 = categorical(t2.Var2);
lm = fitlm(t2, 'Result ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var1:Var2');
anova(lm);
```

This gave the following results:

```
                 SumSq     DF    MeanSq       F        pValue  
                 ______    __    ______    _______    _________

    Var1         69.869     2    34.935      7.307    0.0055666
    Var2         74.901     5     14.98     3.1333     0.036834
    Var1:Var2    22.271     9    2.4745    0.51758      0.84112
    Error        76.495    16    4.7809
```

Yet again, a different result. So then I switched over to Python, and I tried using the `anova_lm` function from the statsmodels module. I tried this in two different ways, first without specifying Var1 and Var2 as categorical, and then the 2nd time I specified them as categorical:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_excel("data_file.xlsx")
model = ols('Result ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var1:Var2', data=df).fit()
sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
```

The results mirrored the results of when I did `fitlm` in Matlab without using categorical variables. Then, trying as cateogorical:

```
model = ols('Result ~ C(Var1) + C(Var2) + C(Var1):C(Var2)', data=df).fit()
sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2)
```

These results *mostly* mirrored the results from Matlab when I used categorical variables, but were not completely identical. Here are the Python results using categorical variables:

```
sum_sq  df  F   PR(>F)
C(Var1) 67.469195   2.0 7.056059    0.006354
C(Var2) 90.625716   5.0 3.791125    0.023617
C(Var1):C(Var2) 24.670662   10.0    0.516021    0.854765
Residual    76.495044   16.0    NaN NaN
```

So, to sum everything up, here are the various results I am getting from various different methods:

[image: Anova results]

So:

1. The Matlab vs Python versions not using categorical variables give identical results.
2. The Matlab vs Python versions using categorical variables give *similar* results (but not identical).
3. *None* of the methods give the same result as the `anovan` Matlab function, which is specifically meant to do an N-way ANOVA on an unbalanced design.

Seeing all of the above, which results should I be using? Can I trust `anovan`? How do I reconcile the differences between `anovan` and the other methods?

Thanks for any help!

[edit]

Just trying another Python module: pingouin. Got yet another different result that doesn't match *any* of the previous results:

```
pg.anova(df, dv="Result", between=["Var1", "Var2"], detailed=True)
```

Result:

```
Source  SS  DF  MS  F   p-unc   np2
0   Var1    47.891240   2.0 23.945620   5.008559    0.020459    0.385020
1   Var2    280.488760  5.0 56.097752   11.733623   0.000068    0.785718
2   Var1 * Var2 48.244576   10.0    4.824458    1.009102    0.476113    0.386762
3   Residual    76.495044   16.0    4.780940    NaN NaN NaN
```

[/edit]

Comment: In unbalanced designs, the individual effects depend on the encoding of the categorical variables. I don't know what matlab is using, but for example SPSS uses a different default encoding than statsmodels, and so unbalanced anova with interaction effects differ unless the same encoding is explicitly used in both.

Comment: I am using Matlab 2022b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem comes from how the software deals with the missing combination of `Var1` and `Var2` when they are treated as factors. I copied your data into an R data frame, set those to factors, and got the following:

```
ftable(anov1$Var1,anov1$Var2)
#    1 2 3 4 5 6
#               
# 1  2 1 0 1 1 1
# 2  3 3 1 2 2 2
# 3  3 2 2 2 2 3
```

You have no cases for which `Var1=1` and `Var2=3`. That's not a problem when you treat them as numeric, but it is when you try to estimate all coefficients including the interaction in a factorial design.

With one 3-level factor, one 6-level factor, and data for all 18 combinations, you would expect 2 degrees of freedom associated with the first, 5 degrees of freedom with the second, and 10 with the interaction term. But you can't get all of those in a factorial ANOVA with a missing cell.

The `anovan` function only listed 1, 4, and 9 degrees of freedom respectively, with one each listed as "singular." Perhaps it just removed both the row and column with the missing data?

The `fitlm` function in Matlab based on categorical predictors gave 2, 5 and 9 degrees of freedom. Perhaps it fit all levels of `Var1` and `Var2` individually but omitted one interaction coefficient that couldn't be estimated? That's what `lm` in R did; it also led to the same analysis of variance table as `fitlm`, via the `car::Anova` function with default Type II sums of squares.

The `anova_lm` function from `statsmodels` and `anova` from `pingouin` somehow both report 2, 5 and 10 degrees of freedom even though there are no data for the `Var1=1;Var2=3` combination. They instead report NaN for residuals tests as a potential warning that something is awry.

The take-home message: if your try to analyze a factorial design without outcome values for one combination of factor levels, you shouldn't take *any* software output at face value.

Comment: or skip anova. There is at least one R/Julia statistician that does not like anova at all. (I never got any intuition for multiway anova with unbalanced samples.)